Mounting volumes in a Dockerfile
When I run a Docker container, I know that if I bind volume foo:bar, the contents of foo on the host will show in bar in the container. However, the --mount option of the RUN command in a Dockerfile does not work the same way. I don't care about the excuse of portable containers, during the execution of the Dockerfile I need to reference an exact volume in the host so that yum will work correctly for what I need it to do. How do I do that?

Create volume and copy content from host to volume?

The content is huge, it contains a private yum repo for an OS whose original repo does not exist anymore.

Make it accessible over a network, or copy the packets you plan to install?

It already is accessible. The NFS volume is mounted on the host under /mnt. I simply want that to show up in the container under /net while the Dockerfile is running.

Mounting directly the nfs share/volume during the build of Dockerfile could be an option? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69014975/6544892

That is an astonishingly convoluted way of doing something that should be simple. I figured out an alternate solution.

I figured out how to do this without jumping a gazillion hoops. I ran the container with -v to mount the folder into the container, then exited the container and committed to a new one. Now I have a container I can work with that has the mount already done.
